# Iterate through nested JSON in Python

Tags: python, json, iterator

```
js = {
   "status": "ok",
   "meta": {
      "count": 1
   },
   "data": {
      "542250529": [
         {
            "all": {
               "spotted": 438,
               "battles_on_stunning_vehicles": 0,
               "avg_damage_blocked": 39.4,
               "capture_points": 40,
               "explosion_hits": 0,
               "piercings": 3519,
               "xp": 376586,
               "survived_battles": 136,
               "dropped_capture_points": 382,
               "damage_dealt": 783555,
               "hits_percents": 74,
               "draws": 2,
               "battles": 290,
               "damage_received": 330011,
               "frags": 584,
               "stun_number": 0,
               "direct_hits_received": 1164,
               "stun_assisted_damage": 0,
               "hits": 4320,
               "battle_avg_xp": 1299,
               "wins": 202,
               "losses": 86,
               "piercings_received": 1004,
               "no_damage_direct_hits_received": 103,
               "shots": 5857,
               "explosion_hits_received": 135,
               "tanking_factor": 0.04
            }
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

Let us name this json "js" as a variable, this variable will be in a for-loop.
To understand better what I'm doing here, I'm trying to collect data from a game.
This game has hundreds of different tanks, each tank has tank_id with which I can post tank_id to the game server and respond the performance data as "js".
`for tank_id: json = requests.post(tank_id) etc...`
and fetch all these values to my database as shown in the screenshot.
[image: database]

my python code for it:

```
def api_get():
 for property in js['data']['542250529']['all']:
   spotted = property['spotted']
   battles_on_stunning_vehicles = property['battles_on_stunning_vehicles']
   # etc
   # ...
   insert_to_db(spotted, battles_on_stunning_vehicles, etc....)
```

the exception is:

```
for property in js['data']['542250529']['all']:
 TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

and when:

```
print(js['data']['542250529'])
```

i get the rest of the js as a string, and i can't iterate... can't be used a valid json string, also what's inside js['data']['542250529'] is a list containing only the item 'all'..., any help would be appreciated

Comment: `542250529` contains a list: `js['data']['542250529'][0]['all']`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just missed `[0]` to get the first item in a list:

```py
def api_get():
   for property in js['data']['542250529'][0]['all']:
       spotted = property['spotted']
# ...
```

Look carefully at the data structure in the source JSON.

Comment: @Master Schifou this will also work.

Comment: I didn't sleep since yesterday trying to find how stupid I am lol, first item in a list get 0 as an index, i appreciate your efforts big boss <3

Answer (score 0):

There is a list containing the dictionary with a key of `all`. So you need to use `js['data']['542250529'][0]['all']` not `js['data']['542250529']['all']`. Then you can use `.items()` to get the key-value pairs.

See below.

```
js = {
   "status": "ok",
   "meta": {
      "count": 1
   },
   "data": {
      "542250529": [
         {
            "all": {
               "spotted": 438,
               "battles_on_stunning_vehicles": 0,
               "avg_damage_blocked": 39.4,
               "capture_points": 40,
               "explosion_hits": 0,
               "piercings": 3519,
               "xp": 376586,
               "survived_battles": 136,
               "dropped_capture_points": 382,
               "damage_dealt": 783555,
               "hits_percents": 74,
               "draws": 2,
               "battles": 290,
               "damage_received": 330011,
               "frags": 584,
               "stun_number": 0,
               "direct_hits_received": 1164,
               "stun_assisted_damage": 0,
               "hits": 4320,
               "battle_avg_xp": 1299,
               "wins": 202,
               "losses": 86,
               "piercings_received": 1004,
               "no_damage_direct_hits_received": 103,
               "shots": 5857,
               "explosion_hits_received": 135,
               "tanking_factor": 0.04
            }
         }
      ]
   }
}

for key, val in js['data']['542250529'][0]['all'].items():
    print("key:", key, " val:", val)

#Or this way

for key in js['data']['542250529'][0]['all']:
    print("key:", key, " val:", js['data']['542250529'][0]['all'][key])
```

Comment: I just found out a solution to make a new for-loop, without knowing how it worked. but thanks to you guys i am doing it the easy way... <3